# How to use ExactTarget SOAP API to only retrieve real Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

We would like to retrieve the list of available Data Extensions in ExactTarget. I'm currently using this SOAP reuqest envelope:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
     </soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
              <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
              <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
              <Properties>Name</Properties>
              <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
           </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
     </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

This works fine, however I note that it also returns results of "things" that aren't data extensions, even though I specify `DataExtension` as `ObjectType`. Refer to example response below.

From what I can figure out, the response **also** includes:

1. [data views](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25656/soap-retrieverequest-returns-internal-data-extension-names) (which I know about)
2. Target Lists from Mobile Connect (denoted below with `CategoryID` : `1104`)
3. and some other internal(?) Data Extension names like `Shopping Cart Items` with `CategoryID` : `14820` and `14831` which I assume are created from the "out of the box" Attribute Groups in Contact Builder.

The question is, how can I filter this list to **only** return actual Data Extensions? That is Data Extensions that we have created in Email > Subscribers > Data Extensions?

Perhaps if I know what specific category IDs to search for, I can do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:2f1f6afb-6b43-4a08-b5d5-b34884c9804b</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:c643d8cd-1239-4f26-bf82-e15699ae49b2</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-7398199b-4adc-45e8-b98a-2330b95f7186">
                <wsu:Created>2014-10-06T05:07:16Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2014-10-06T05:12:16Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>f20cac26-feca-43f1-9f0c-5d846d0be19f</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>79F64C3F-CF3F-4928-A90B-0C86327E75C1</CustomerKey>
                <Name>_MobileAddress</Name>
                <CategoryID>1104</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>0CDF18E9-A4F8-4F4E-B8D3-44F296F51C8E</CustomerKey>
                <Name>SMSCampaignA</Name>
                <CategoryID>1104</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>3F802E0E-CFE4-44B1-8158-53BA1BD430FB</CustomerKey>
                <Name>SMSCampaignB</Name>
                <CategoryID>1104</CategoryID>
            </Results>
           <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>134AC210-F379-4561-A28F-932CA0F6FAF1</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Locations</Name>
                <CategoryID>14816</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>466688C0-42C6-4109-B0D9-AF6F7D5F1372</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Airports</Name>
                <CategoryID>14816</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>FE065BCD-7F80-4968-9977-7D33C0079AD7</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Hotels</Name>
                <CategoryID>14816</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>7BC041D2-CC0A-4822-9C4F-E2487A852948</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Weather</Name>
                <CategoryID>14816</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>51A58862-3A9C-498E-A44A-F8AC1700F805</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Flight History</Name>
                <CategoryID>14816</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>98FDDF28-7151-473B-B484-0556001DFF59</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Hotel History</Name>
                <CategoryID>14816</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>11132505-E4A6-400E-A5E1-460042FAA19C</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Booking Demographics</Name>
                <CategoryID>14816</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>64071C5A-7209-43D7-8BD1-B52204B761EA</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Flight History Airport</Name>
                <CategoryID>14816</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>BD927A29-8E9F-4D36-AD30-6ED84055FEE1</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Product Views</Name>
                <CategoryID>14820</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>D765DCC0-59EF-47B6-ABF8-52788260E2C0</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Shopping Cart Products</Name>
                <CategoryID>14820</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>5D741812-7504-4F03-867A-0617A30561AB</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Shopping Cart</Name>
                <CategoryID>14820</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>3BB6BC7B-AFAF-4209-A921-08C64EA8E4B2</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Shopping Cart Items</Name>
                <CategoryID>14820</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>435D458D-4E6E-4AFF-967A-4343AA6E8EC4</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Retail Orders</Name>
                <CategoryID>14831</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>2505ADBE-2FA1-4E54-B911-AC4D105DE86D</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Retail Order Lines</Name>
                <CategoryID>14831</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>F46FB885-0022-470C-908A-162BEA822F0E</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Retail Products</Name>
                <CategoryID>14831</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>1A671979-6756-4165-9E38-DFAD89AFC265</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Returns</Name>
                <CategoryID>14831</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>684D8EFD-F1BC-45DD-8B3E-97C4289F9369</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Return Lines</Name>
                <CategoryID>14831</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>891B3724-D24C-4446-90A4-C9696675C04E</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Payments</Name>
                <CategoryID>14831</CategoryID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>85F067D0-BD6E-469C-A9D3-9737EC32CADD</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Credits</Name>
                <CategoryID>14831</CategoryID>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been asking around, and unfortunately, there does not appear to be a direct way to do what you want to do.  If you have a certain naming convention on your DE, you could use that, but there is no internal system flag that marks something as "system created" or what have you.

Good luck!