# Is it possible to build a custom Profile Center using the SOAP API without Ampscript?

Tags: profile, soap

I have been able to read a Subscriber and list all the custom questions and the answer the Subscriber gave.

What I need to do is list all the questions, know what kind of question (Yes/No, multiple choice, free text) so I can create the right kind of HTML control (radio, drop-down, text box...), know all the possible choices for each question (for radio and drop-down style questions), and know the Subscriber's answer.

I don't believe all the properties of the all the questions are available from the Subscriber object. (I believe I only have the text of the question and the text of the answer.) It seems like the object that our admins manipulate when they log in to the Exact Target UI and create these Profile Attributes and Preferences, setting all the properties of each question, should be the object I'm requesting from the SOAP API.

This exists in Ampscript. (http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api/) (I want to avoid Ampscript so I can host the page on our own server.) In Ampscript, the command appears to be LOOKUPORDEREDROWS. This is an Ampscript method, not part of the SOAP API, and the documentation doesn't show how it works. I need to know how to get this functionality from the SOAP API. Also, I may be wrong. This LOOKUPORDEREDROWS might actually be only for Data Extensions and not Profile Preferences and Profile Attributes.

Is this possible? Has anyone done this before? I need hints, pointers, examples...

Comment: This might have a clue: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51446/how-to-use-exacttarget-soap-api-to-only-retrieve-real-data-extensions. I wonder if one of the non-data-extensions objects returned is the list of Profile Attributes and Preferences I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and I'm well on my way. This email from help@exacttarget is the information I had the hardest time finding for this:

```
<DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <DescribeRequests>
            <ClientIDs>
               <ID>______________</ID>
            </ClientIDs>
            <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
               <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
            </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
         </DescribeRequests>
      </DefinitionRequestMsg>
```

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/describing_a_subscriber/

I hope this answer helps someone else get over the hump.