# How to bulk export MobileConnect SMS subscriptions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Is it possible to automate a bulk export of MobileConnect subscriptions? I don't see much documentation on the matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two data views with limited/no documentation (as of time of writing) that store SMS data that can be accessed by a Query Activity:

**_MobileAddress**

```
| Field Name      | Data Type (Length) | Required (Y/N) | Data Default |
| :-              | :-                 | :-:            | :-           |
| _ContactID      | Text               | Y              |              |
| _MobileNumber   | Text(15)           | Y              |              |
| _Status         | Text               | N              |              |
| _Source         | Text               | N              |              |
| _SourceObjectId | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _Priority       | Text               | N              | 1            |
| _Channel        | Text(20)           | N              |              |
| _CarrierID      | Text               | Y              | 0            |
| _CountryCode    | Text(2)            | Y              |              |
| _CreatedDate    | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _CreatedBy      | Text               | N              |              |
| _ModifiedDate   | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _ModifiedBy     | Text               | N              |              |
| _City           | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _State          | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _ZipCode        | Text(20)           | N              |              |
| _FirstName      | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _LastName       | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _UTCOffset      | Decimal(4,2)       | N              | 0            |
| _IsHonorDST     | Boolean            | N              | false        |
```

**_MobileSubscription**

```
| Field Name                | Data Type (Length) | Required (Y/N) | Data Default |
| :-                        | :-                 | :-:            | :-           |
| _SubscriptionDefinitionID | Text(200)          | Y              |              |
| _MobileNumber             | Text(15)           | Y              |              |
| _OptOutStatusID           | Text               | N              |              |
| _OptOutMethodID           | Text               | N              |              |
| _OptOutDate               | Date               | N              |              |
| _OptInStatusID            | Text               | Y              |              |
| _OptInMethodID            | Text               | N              |              |
| _OptInDate                | Date               | N              |              |
| _Source                   | Text               | N              |              |
| _CreatedDate              | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _CreatedBy                | Text               | N              |              |
| _ModifiedDate             | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _ModifiedBy               | Text               | N              |              |
```

Comment: Can you bulk import to these tables if you have a list of contacts that have opted back in?

Comment: Hi @jack - sorry for the slow reply on this. But, as with any system data view, you cannot bulk import to these tables. You'd likely need to go through the REST service to update a subscription.

Comment: These data views are no longer supported and have been replaced by SMSSubscriptionLog and SMSMessageTracking. There is not a direct replacement for MobileAddress and if you are using it it should not break.