# Retrieving a Subscriber mobile number and email using SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

We're creating Contacts in Marketing Cloud using the REST API [createContacts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createContacts.htm) method. This works really well — in a single request we are able to create:

1. an Email Subscriber (that appears in the All Subscribers list)
2. a mobile Subscriber (in MobileConnect)
3. Subscriber Attributes (in Attribute Sets/Populations within the Contact model)

We can then use the [searchSchema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/searchSchema.htm) to search for these 
Contacts. For example, the following request:

```json
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributes/search
{
    "request": {
        "attributes": [{
                "key": "Email Addresses.Email Address"
            },
            {
                "key": "MobileConnect Demographics.Mobile Number"
            }]

    },
    "conditionSet": {
        "operator": "And",
        "conditionSets": [],
        "conditions": [{
            "attribute": {
                "key": "Contacts.Contact Key"
            },
            "operator": "Equals",
            "value": {
                "items": ["25eb9b5f-a979-37eb-6595-ffc415d6e654"]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Returns:

```json
{
  "page": 1,
  "pageSize": 50,
  "count": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "values": [
        {
          "id": "75d77da9-1764-e611-97ba-8cdcd4a8b025",
          "key": "MobileConnect Demographics.Mobile Number",
          "name": "Mobile Number",
          "value": "61402123456"
        },
        {
          "id": "42d77da9-1764-e611-97ba-8cdcd4a8b025",
          "key": "Email Addresses.Email Address",
          "name": "Email Address",
          "value": "someone@sample.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": {},
  "requestServiceMessageID": "ba2e0692-b2e0-47d5-8320-3d594f7a4398",
  "resultMessages": [],
  "serviceMessageID": "9568bf7e-55f2-45d9-a518-e7dcf88941aa"
}
```

This is fine, but we want to retrieve a mobile number and email address for a known Subscriber/Contact using an SQL query.

Is a MobileConnect list and the All Subscribers list accessible from an SQL query?

We could always write an SSJS Script Activity to use the Marketing Cloud REST API to retrieve the response payload and insert the values into a Data Extension, but I'd rather use an SQL query if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a way to fetch MobileConnect subscribers. Just check out [How to bulk export MobileConnect SMS subscriptions?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-to-bulk-export-mobileconnect-sms-subscriptions)

Answer (score -1):

Mobile connect cannot be accessed via SQL, however all subscribers can.

Refer to All subscribers as "_subscribers" in your SQL query. If using an Enterprise 2.0 account and you want to reference the parent level all subscribers, use "ent._subscribers".
FOR example (Replace value for subscriber key with your known contact):

```
Select EmailAddress from _subscribers with (nolock) where subscriberkey = ''
```