# Viewing MobilePush Attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, contactbuilder

We're using the MobilePush SDK to add Attributes to a Contact using the addAttribute() function as [documented here](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/attributes.html).

We have also added the attributes in Marketing Cloud by:

1. Open MobilePush Data Attribute Group in Contact Builder
2. Edit the 'MobilePush Demographics' Attribute Set
3. Add the required Attributes

This is fine, but we can't figure out where we can view these Attributes. I would have assumed that they appear in the Contact Record view accessible from:

Contact Builder > All Contacts > [Contact Record] > Attributes Tab > MobilePush Data Section

I note that custom Attributes for Email Demographics and MobileConnect Data appear here, but not for MobilePush Demographics.

All I want to do is to see MobilePush Attributes for a Contact! Note that there is:

1. No SQL Data View for this
2. No Data Extension
3. No visibility in the Contact Record (in Contact Builder)

Does anyone know how to Attributes for MobilePush Contacts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eliot,

Great question. This is a bit unintuitive. To view the attributes:

1. Login to Marketing Cloud
2. Navigate to Mobile Push
3. In the upper right-ish corner of the dashboard, in the contacts box, click the manage button
4. (optionally) Search for a contactKey / subscriberKey
5. Click on the contact key link for a selected contact
6. Click the attributes tab
7. Scroll down until you see the Mobile Push Demographics

Your attribute data will appear there, for the contact you selected.

Comment: As per my question, that's precisely where I looked but the data is not there. I'll check with support before confirming your answer.

Comment: Eliot, I was trying to make a distinction between viewing a contact in contact builder, and viewing it via the mobile push contacts viewer. Does that help? if not, send me a private message, and we'll work out a time to screen share.

Comment: Kevin, I see the same issue if I view from MobilePush. I reached out to Salesforce support who advised that the "contacts schema is out of sync for our account". The database team is fixing this for us. I will accept your answer, as you are correct that this is the right place to look!

Comment: I followed the steps, but I see that the Edit button is disabled for my Mobile Push and Mobile Connect Demographics attributes. Why is that? how to enable? @KevinP

Answer (score 7):

There is a Data View for MobilePush demographics similar to that of MobileConnect

`_PushAddress` contains the MobilePush Demographics data

`_MobileAddress` contains the MobileConnect Demographics data

Field with a `_` prefix are system attributes, any without are typically the additional (custom) attributes you may have added.

Hope this helps, if you need further details please message me and I can provide some more info.

Comment: Thanks, this is great to know! Can you share the fields that we can query from these views?

Comment: _MobileAddress attributes: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-to-bulk-export-mobileconnect-sms-subscriptions/76784#76784