# Attributes in _PushAddress and _PushTag Data Views

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, data-views

Relating to this question:
[Viewing MobilePush Attributes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155607/viewing-mobilepush-attributes/155612#155612)

Looking for the attribute names for both of these data views that support mobile push.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the following from the DataExtensionField retrieve request:

_PushAddress:

```
| Field Name       | Data Type (Length) | Required (Y/N) | Data Default |
| :-               | :-                 | :-:            | :-           |
| _ContactID       | Text               | Y              |              |
| _DeviceID        | Text(200)          | Y              |              |
| _APID            | Text(38)           | Y              |              |
| _Status          | Text               | N              |              |
| _Source          | Text               | N              |              |
| _SourceObjectId  | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _Platform        | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _PlatformVersion | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _Alias           | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _OptOutStatusID  | Text               | N              |              |
| _OptOutMethodID  | Text               | N              |              |
| _OptOutDate      | Date               | N              |              |
| _OptInStatusID   | Text               | Y              | 0            |
| _OptInMethodID   | Text               | N              |              |
| _OptInDate       | Date               | N              |              |
| _Channel         | Text(20)           | N              |              |
| _CreatedDate     | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _CreatedBy       | Text               | N              |              |
| _ModifiedDate    | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _ModifiedBy      | Text               | N              |              |
| _City            | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _State           | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _ZipCode         | Text(20)           | N              |              |
| _FirstName       | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _LastName        | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _UTCOffset       | Decimal(4,2)       | N              | 0            |
| _IsHonorDST      | Boolean            | N              | false        |
| _SystemToken     | Text(4000)         | N              |              |
| _ProviderToken   | Text(200)          | N              |              |
| _Badge           | Number             | N              |              |
| _LocationEnabled | Boolean            | N              |              |
| _TimeZone        | Text(50)           | N              |              |
| _Device          | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _HardwareId      | Text(100)          | N              |              |
| _DeviceType      | Text(20)           | N              |              |
```

_PushTag:

```
| Field Name    | Data Type (Length) | Required (Y/N) | Data Default |
| :-            | :-                 | :-:            | :-           |
| _DeviceID     | Text(200)          | Y              |              |
| _APID         | Text(38)           | Y              |              |
| _Value        | Text(128)          | N              |              |
| _CreatedDate  | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _CreatedBy    | Text               | N              |              |
| _ModifiedDate | Date               | Y              | GETDATE()    |
| _ModifiedBy   | Text               | N              |              |
```

Comment: Appreciate you cleaning this answer up Adam. :)

Comment: The field "Last Application Open" is also available by SQL. If you want to edit your response.

Comment: how to query those fields that begin with _?

Comment: Hey @zeljazouli ...may I know how to query "Last Application Open"?

Comment: @eeadev you just have to alias the column names:  https://gist.github.com/wvpv/d39ee39345f799fc0193b416a7b5e2e0

Comment: I am unable to query "Last Application Open", how did you do it @zeljazouli ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to use alias

```
select  _APID as APPID, 
        _SystemToken as Token,
        _DeviceID as deviceID,
        _HardwareId as Hardware,
        _Device as Device
        from _PushAddress
```