# Mobile Push Contact Info to Email Studio/Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobilepush, contactbuilder, email-studio

In my data schema, I have information going into the Mobile Push contact attributes. Unfortunately, I do not know how to bring this data into the Email Studio/Contact Builder.

I would like to do this because if I can get this information into a Data Extension, then I believe I could utilize this information for Journey Builder/Automation Studio.

Does anyone have any ideas if/how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**this post**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/174180/5202) the `_MobilePush` system data view includes the following:

```
| Name             | FieldType | MaxLength | IsRequired |
| :-               | :-        | :-        | :-         |
| _Alias           | Text      | 100       | FALSE      |
| _APID            | Text      | 38        | TRUE       |
| _Badge           | Number    | FALSE     |            |
| _Channel         | Text      | 20        | FALSE      |
| _City            | Text      | 200       | FALSE      |
| _ContactID       | Text      | TRUE      |            |
| _CreatedBy       | Text      | FALSE     |            |
| _CreatedDate     | Date      | TRUE      |            |
| _Device          | Text      | 100       | FALSE      |
| _DeviceID        | Text      | 200       | TRUE       |
| _DeviceType      | Text      | 20        | FALSE      |
| _FirstName       | Text      | 100       | FALSE      |
| _HardwareId      | Text      | 100       | FALSE      |
| _IsHonorDST      | Boolean   | FALSE     |            |
| _LastName        | Text      | 100       | FALSE      |
| _LocationEnabled | Boolean   | FALSE     |            |
| _ModifiedBy      | Text      | FALSE     |            |
| _ModifiedDate    | Date      | TRUE      |            |
| _OptInDate       | Date      | FALSE     |            |
| _OptInMethodID   | Text      | FALSE     |            |
| _OptInStatusID   | Text      | TRUE      |            |
| _OptOutDate      | Date      | FALSE     |            |
| _OptOutMethodID  | Text      | FALSE     |            |
| _OptOutStatusID  | Text      | FALSE     |            |
| _Platform        | Text      | 100       | FALSE      |
| _PlatformVersion | Text      | 100       | FALSE      |
| _ProviderToken   | Text      | 200       | FALSE      |
| _Source          | Text      | FALSE     |            |
| _SourceObjectId  | Text      | 200       | FALSE      |
| _State           | Text      | 200       | FALSE      |
| _Status          | Text      | FALSE     |            |
| _SystemToken     | Text      | 4000      | FALSE      |
| _TimeZone        | Text      | 50        | FALSE      |
| _UTCOffset       | Decimal   | 4         | FALSE      |
| _ZipCode         | Text      | 20        | FALSE      |
```

Comment: This is definitely a good start. But this seems to only address system fields. What I really need is to get my custom Mobile Push data onto a data extension. Do you know if this can accept custom data? Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to create a DE with the above columns (minus the underscore prefixes) and write a query activity to make a copy.