# A few fields in MobilePush Demographics

Tags: mobilepush

I've found the [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174179/attributes-in-pushaddress-and-pushtag-data-views) that gives some of the field names for MobilePush Demographics.  I'm still trying to track down a few fields:

Send Count
Message Open Count
Last Message Open
Last Send

Is it possible to extract this in a data extension?

Comment: Making no assumptions; did you try to access them via `SendCount` or `_SendCount` (same pattern for others) because they're plainly visible from the UI for me.

Comment: Yes.  Every variation of those I could think of, for all of the fields I'm trying to retrieve

Comment: IDK then Justin, but I upvoted your question.