# Mapping between Contact Key and Contact ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, contactbuilder, data-views

I have found this article which outlines the data available within mobilpush data views.

[Attributes in _PushAddress and _PushTag Data Views](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174179/attributes-in-pushaddress-and-pushtag-data-views)

However i have not been able to find a way to retrieve the ContactKey used in other parts of Marketing Cloud.

All my data designer is correct but i just cant figure out how to get a mapping between ContactID and ContactKey.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Update** Based on a comment i did run a test between subscribers and mobile push data views and you cant do a join as suspected as subscriber has to exist in the email channel to be included. So any further Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: My assumption: There has to be a system table in salesforce where only IDs reside. Let me call it SYSTEM_IDs (it is not the tablename). There you will have a Contact ID, Contact Key,  MobileAddress , the PushID, ... Therefore it is a one to one relationship. For the more experienced ones: Please correct me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an update. I have spoken to Salesforce and they have confirmed there is currently no way to map the key and id UNLESS the contact has also subscribed to an SMS/Email channel as those data views allow you to join on ID to get the Key.

They also  no longer provide the all contacts data view.

So in summary if the contact is only subscribed on the mobilepush channel there is no way to extract the contact ID/KEY mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Your Contact Key in _Subscribers is SubscriberKey

Your Contact ID in _Subscribers is SubscriberID

Your Contact Key in _MobileAddress should be _ContactKey

Are you looking to build your own related data views? What other data are you trying to relate?

Comment: Hi @matthew-wash my understanding is that a contact will only exist in  _Subscribers if they are used in the email platform. Some of the contacts i am interested in are only in the push Channel. The SDK sets the Contact Key as a ID i can use in other systems as well as other locations within marketing cloud but as per the link i provided there is no ContactKey in any push data view