# How to query "Last Application Open" & "Last Send" from _PushAddress or other relevant data view?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, mobilepush, data-views

I can query the system attributes from the _PushAddress data view as listed here:

- [Attributes in _PushAddress and _PushTag Data Views](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174179/attributes-in-pushaddress-and-pushtag-data-views/174180#174180)

But I am unable to fetch the "Last Application Open" & "Last Send" attributes from the data view.

I've tried querying like

```
SELECT [Last Application Open] as 'LastAppOpen'
FROM _PushAddress
```

and

```
 SELECT [LastAppOpen] as 'LastAppOpen'
FROM _PushAddress
```

but it returns error on validation:

> Invalid column name.

I want to know if it's possible to query these two fields for Mobile Push from the system views?

Comment: I cannot see the field `Last Application Open` in that list of field in the link you provided. Do you know the field exists?

Comment: @Robs The fields exists in the MobilePush Demographics system object.
Additionally according to the comment by zeljazouli this field is available via sql.

Comment: The list of fields for `_PushAddress` does not include it, is there any other documentation which indicates the field should be available?

Comment: @Robs I couldn't find any official documentation on which fields should be available in the system view.
But these fields do exist in the MobilePush Demographics system object by default as I just checked in a different account. 
If these fields are not available in the _PushAddress view I hope to find an alternative source to query

Comment: Update on this, DataExtensionField retrieve request doesn't return the "Last Application Open" & "Last Send" columns - although these fields and the values are visible per Contact in the attributes tab in the All Contacts.

Comment: @ssr90 - Were you able to identify the system object that could be queried for this? I have a similar requirement and am unable to do so.