# How to retrieve a demographics field in a push notification via ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, mobilepush, push

In my outbound push notification, I am trying to get a demographics field using ampscript but I am not getting anything.

For instance having this:

[image]

what is the Ampscript code to get the value corrisponding to the field **Application**?

Answer (score 2):

Since the MobilePush Demographics is not directly accessible using a `Lookup()`, what you can do is try to get the data from the `_PushAddress` Data View.

Only problem with that is you can't Look for your value using your `ContactKey`, you can only use your `ContactID`. If you want to use the `ContactKey` you should at first look for your `ContactID` using the `ContactKey` and then use it to find your attribute in a second lookup. But this will work only if the contact is in Subscribers.

your AmpScript should be something like this :

```
%%[

var @Application, @ContactID
set @ContactID = subscriberid
set @Application = Lookup("_PushAddress", "_APID", "_ContactID", @ContactID)

]%%
```

The full list of _PushAddress Attributes can be found here : [Attributes in _PushAddress and _PushTag Data Views](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174179/attributes-in-pushaddress-and-pushtag-data-views)