# Rest API Method

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush

Does the REST API support querying mobile push demographics?

How to retrieve mobile push demographics data for a given contact key ?

I searched the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/attributeSetsDataName.htm , but could not find any relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if there is a direct way to do it. However, there is a data view containing the information.
[Attributes in _PushAddress and _PushTag Data Views](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174179/attributes-in-pushaddress-and-pushtag-data-views?rq=1)

So you could have an automation running getting the info from that data view and write it to a data extension. That data extension can then be accessed with REST API.