# How can we access 'LastOpenApp' , LastOpenPush', 'LastSendMobilePush' attributes from SFMC data views?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

How can we access 'LastOpenApp' ,  LastOpenPush', 'LastSendMobilePush' attributes from SFMC data views?

Answer (score 1):

Please start by reading this article:
[Attributes in _PushAddress and _PushTag Data Views](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174179/attributes-in-pushaddress-and-pushtag-data-views)

In the comments its already mentioned, that the list there is not entirely up to date. Therefore, try querying those values from the *_PushAddress* Data View.