# Querying Mobile Push Demographics Table

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, mobilepush, data-views, data-designer

I'm attempting to query our mobile push demographics table that's tied to the contact record to pull some Application Version data and I'm struggling in Query Studio.

The name of the table is MobilePush Demographics.

I've attempted FROM:

[MobilePush Demographics], __[MobilePush Demographics], ent.[MobilePush Demographics], ent._[MobilePush Demographics]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper name for the Mobile PushDemographics data view is `_PushAddress`.

There's an answer made by @Daniel that lists all default fields and their datatype [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/174180/39888), but be aware that you your data extension field names can't begin with an underscore, so when you query this data view, you need to rename them using an alias, for example:

```
Select
    _ContactID as ContactID
From
    _PushAddress
```

If you have any custom attributes added to MobilePush Demographics, their names in this data view will not be proceeded by an underscore, so using an alias won't be needed.