# Adding device OptIn field to SQL query in Mark. Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

I have SQL running from a Data extension where I have all marketing opted in contacts, now I need to add a field to the SQL with the device level Opt in and Out options as I will further use these in a journey, where customers who opted in will receive a push and those who opted out will get an email.
I'm not sure how to write this query. I wanted to join it with _PushAddress data view table but it doesn't have a Subscriber key to match it with the Subscriber key. I could perhaps join it with a Filtered Mobile List but do I make it using 2 filters: OptedIn=2 and OptedIn=1? I'd appreciate any suggestions as to what source I can use to join with the current data extension. My SQL query looks like this for the time being:

SELECT
a.Email
a.Campaign
a.Subscriberkey
b.OptIn
b.OptOut
FROM DataExtension1
INNER JOIN
...
on a.Subscriberkey=...

Answer (score 0):

`_PushAddress` does not have a subscriberKey field, please check these two posts for complete schema

https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/174180/28187

I am not sure if _PushAddress._ContactID is the same as subscriberKey/contactkey, so you can try `left join` to check if you can get any matching records. by using `left join` you can include all email subscribers regardless whether they have a _Push optin status.

```
SELECT a.Email
,a.Campaign
,a.Subscriberkey
,b.[_OptInStatusID] as 'DeviceOptin'
FROM DataExtension1 a LEFT JOIN (_PushAddress) b 
on a.Subscriberkey=b.[_ContactID]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, If I use only OptInStatus as deviceOptIn, it will not include any OptedOut contacts in the data extension and I need them to send them an email.

Comment: I guess in that case I can add a field called 'DeviceOptOut' as well to this SQL then

Comment: SubscriberK and contactID cannot be matched, so I need to use a mobile Filtered List. Just not sure  if I have add 2 filters to my list: opted in - true and opted out-true? So that means that I have to add both optIn and OptOut fields to my query which is not what I was asked to do, I need one field only .

Comment: Mobile filtered list also doesn't have a Subscriber Key so I cannto match it...