# Can I join on a Contact ID with Subscriber ID in my SQL?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm writing a SQL where I need to join _PushAddress with _Subscribers in Marketing Cloud. I'm not sure if these values are the same and if I can use them for a join?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM _PushAddress a
Inner Join
_Subscribers b
ON a.ContactID=b.SubscriberID
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `ContactID` and `SubscriberID` values are the same, but you need to pay attention to the little detail in [_PushAddress](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174179/attributes-in-pushaddress-and-pushtag-data-views): all attributes here have an underscore (`_`) prefix, so you need to alias all of them to be able to retrieve them and write them to a data extension with an SQL query.

For all other values you just need to list columns in the following way:
`a._DeviceID as DeviceID`

This also means that the value, you're joining on (`a.ContactID`) should actually be `a._ContactID`.

If the app is implemented on a child business unit on an Enterprise 2.0 account, you would need to run the query on that business unit and add the `ENT.` prefix to `_Subscribers`.

Comment: Thank you so much!