# Mobile Push - Purge old device entries

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, push

is it possible to delete / purge **device level** Mobile push records?

Use case - we have a large database and some customers have multiple devices (opted out and opted in). We'd like to implement a hygiene process (business logic TBC) to remove old dormant records.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it shouldn't, but it really is as simple as this:

```js
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load('Core', '1');

    var deviceId = 'D3L7T10N-CR4P-W1LL-B333-3X73RM1N473D'

    try {
        var pushAddress = DataExtension.Init('_PushAddress');
        var removal = pushAddress.Rows.Remove(["_DeviceID"], [deviceId]);
    } catch (error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }
</script>
```

In this case `removal` will return `1` when the record removal is successful and `0` otherwise.

It really is just a data extension that you can freely modify. You can do a simple lookup on rows before and after to see if this works for you.

Refer to this post for details about this '*data view*':
[Attributes in _PushAddress and _PushTag Data Views](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174179/attributes-in-pushaddress-and-pushtag-data-views)

Before you do the deletion, be sure to back the data up and do a thorough review of the attributes that get stored in the record that you will be deleting.

Comment: Thanks Rafal - who'd have thought it'd be so easy!