# How can I query MobilePush Demographics to filter on Application Version?

Tags: mobilepush, mobilesdk, app

Based on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174179/attributes-in-pushaddress-and-pushtag-data-views/174180#174180) I understand that _pushaddress is the data view that should be queried for MobilePush Demographics.

However I notice there are some attributes visible on the MobilePush Demographics UI that are not available in _pushaddress this includes "Application Version" along with some other fields.

I want to confirm which backend table (data view) can be used as source object for querying app versions? I just want to write the app version against the contact ID and pass it over for further analysis downstream.

Any help would be appreciated!