# Exporting data from Marketing Cloud MobilePush

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export, mobilepush

We have a filtered Data extension in MobilePush (SFMC) that contains all customers who have logged into the app.

We need to feed that information back to our data warehouse.

**How do we export a filter from MobilePush?**

- Can a query access MobilePush and retrieve the data (we mimic the filter criteria in the query) > which loads it into a DE > which we then simply export.

If the above works how table alias do we need to use in our query? I have looked and cannot find any documentation on this. Sure someone else must have needed to do this as well.

Comment: Sorry. Are you referring to data you have in a Data Extension that you're trying to extract, or are you trying to query MobilePush data that sits outside Data Extensions? I'm just unclear what "query access MobilePush" means.

Comment: Maybe this will help-http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-to-bulk-export-mobileconnect-sms-subscriptions

Comment: Hi Palash - Yes that will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two data views are available but no documentation is available at the moment on Marketing Cloud wiki. you should use both the mentioned data view to get MobilePush data by a query activity.

```
1._MobileAddress
2._MobileSubscription
```

Go through the below link and hope this may help you!

[How to bulk export MobileConnect SMS subscriptions?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-to-bulk-export-mobileconnect-sms-subscriptions/76784#76784)

Answer (score 1):

There is no documentation on MobilePush Data views at the time of this response.  However, that was once true of MobileConnect and I had success in using Contact Builder to reference the schema of MobileConnect for querying.

Therefore, I'd recommend you try the same thing for MobilePush - I have attached a screenshot of the MobilePush schema as defined within Contact Builder for reference.

[image: MobilePush Contact Builder Schema Reference]