# MobileConnect Send Time Variables?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Does anyone know the send time variables for Mobile Connect?

I'm used to e.g. @subcsriberkey = _subscriberKey, but what are the equivalent for mobile connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to [this page](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/) for a complete list of personalization strings available within MobileConnect.

### Retrieving Email Subscriber details from MobileConnect

The good news is that SubscriberId in Email Demographics matches the ContactId in the Contact model. So to retrieve the Subscriber Key of the Contact in an SMS, you can lookup the `_ContactID` from the mobile [data view](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-to-bulk-export-mobileconnect-sms-subscriptions) and then use this to retrieve email subscriber details from the [Subscribers data view](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/).

Use the following code in a MobileConnect message template to send an SMS containing the Subscriber Key and Email Address of a Contact:

```javascript
%%[
var @contactId, @subscriberKey, @emailAddress
set @contactId = Lookup('_MobileAddress','_ContactID','_MobileNumber',MOBILE_NUMBER)
set @subscriberKey = Lookup('Ent._Subscribers','SubscriberKey','SubscriberID',@contactId)
set @emailAddress = Lookup('Ent._Subscribers','EmailAddress','SubscriberID',@contactId)
]%%
Subscriber Key: %%=v(@subscriberKey)=%%
Email Address: %%=v(@emailAddress)=%%
```

**Note** if you are sending from the Parent Business Unit, then you can remove the `Ent.` prefix.

I've tested this by sending an SMS to myself and it works fine.

Comment: Can it be true that contact key / subscriber key, isn't available? Can this be retrieved via ampscript from a system table? (Instead of mapping DE) ?

Comment: That's a great question. Yes, this is possible and I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hey Eliot - one thing i stumpled across:
--> https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/personalization_strings_and_ampscript/
-->
versus
-->
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/

I stumbled across it because you use MOBILE_NUMBER, where as the first link you show uses _MobileNumber, and the second link correctly shows the mobile_number as you used.

Single source of truth is the second link or? :)

Comment: That's a good question. I did try using `_MobileNumber` as the documentation indicated but that did not work (it did not send the SMS). It appears that the personalization strings referenced in the documentation actually refer to the [MobileAddress Data View](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-to-bulk-export-mobileconnect-sms-subscriptions) and are not personalization strings. (https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/). I will let the documentation team know.

Comment: FYI, there are other AMPscript variables that you can use in SMS messages that are [documented here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/) and these are helpful for retrieving keywords and messages in Mobile Originated (MO) messages.

Comment: @EliotHarper - The link you provided at the beginning of your answer seems to have broken. Any chance you could update? I really need that page and am having a devilish time finding it.

Comment: @Will I've updated the link. The MobileConnect Data Strings at https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/ is the most comprehensive list.