# How to retrieve "Contact Key" in a text response

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have a list of contacts from the Sales Cloud that I have imported into a MobileConnect list. I stored the Id of a Person Account record from  Sales Cloud as the "Contact Key". Here's the CSV file that I have used to import the contact into the MobileConnect list.

_MobileNumber,_LastName,_FirstName,_Email,_CountryCode,_ContactKey
91990007913,Smith,Jane,jane@smith.com.au,AU,0019000003edTguAAE

I mapped the _ContactKey column to the "Contact Key" field on the MobileConnect list. The contact was imported and I can see that the Id from the Person Account record of the Sales Cloud is now the Contact Key in the Marketing Cloud.

I have set up a campaign whereupon receiving a keyword from the subscriber, I want to update a specific field in the Sales Cloud Contact record.

I have used the following lines of code in my Text Response message associated with the keyword. From the various articles and stackexchange questions and answers, I gather that the Contact Key is the SubscriberKey

[image: Outbound Response Code]

Here's the text representation of the code. I couldn't get the formatting right. When I try sending an Outbound message and responding with the TESTBED keyword, all I get in response is "There was an error processing your message.". I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
%%[ 
var @response, @contactId, @subscriberKey, @result 

if trim(uppercase([MSG(0).NOUN(0)])) == "TESTBED" 
    set @contactId = Lookup("_MobileAddress","_ContactID","_MobileNumber",mobile_number) 

    set @subscriberKey = Lookup("_Subscribers","SubscriberKey","SubscriberID",@contactId) 

    set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account",@subscriberKey,"Opt_Out__c","true") 

    set @response = CONCAT("TESTBED message received. Thank you.", " Opt Out Result is ", @result) 
else 
    set @response = "Sorry, we did not recognise your response." 
]%% 

%%=v(@response)=%%
```

Comment: i think there is an issue with your `Lookup` function, is you DataExtension name _MobileAddress and _Subscribers?

Comment: Thanks for responding Abhiskhek.

_MobileAddress and _Subscribers are standard inbuilt data views in the Marketing Cloud according to the following links: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/contacts/previous_version_of_contacts/

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_subscribers/


I borrowed code that the Elliot Harper posted on this article - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169146/mobileconnect-send-time-variables for my use-case

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I can see that for variable @contactId you have used a mobile number personalization string as `mobile_number` try changing that to `MOBILE_NUMBER`. Personalization string should always be written as they are mentioned. you can visit https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/ for more information

Comment: Thanks, Abhishek, that change (MOBILE_NUMBER). Still getting the same error. Must be something else. I've also raised a support ticket on the partner portal to open up my reach for this problem. If I am able to resolve this, I'll update my post there.

Answer (score 2):

After speaking with Marketing Cloud support, I was advised to store the Salesforce Id for a Contact or Account in a custom field (SF_ID of type text) in the Mobile Demographics.
[image: New field in the mobile demographics using the data designer]

I was able to make use of the _MobileAddress data view to get the value from the SF_ID custom field. Also, while importing contacts in MobileConnect, I had to map the Salesforce Id field to the SF_ID custom field.

Here's the final code that worked for me:

```
%%[
var @response, @contactId, @subscriberKey, @result 

if trim(uppercase([MSG(0).VERB])) == "TESTBED" then
    set @subscriberKey = Lookup("_MobileAddress","SF_ID","_MobileNumber",MOBILE_NUMBER)
    set @response = CONCAT("Message received. You have been opted out.)
    set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account",@subscriberKey,"Opt_Out__c","true")
else
    set @response = CONCAT("Sorry, we did not recognise your response.", " NOUN value is: ", uppercase([MSG(0).VERB]))
endif
]%%

%%=v(@response)=%%
```